# how do i set a py game rect's posision after rect is set up

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using:

```
check = pygame.image.load("check.png")
checkrect = check.get_rect()
checkrect = checkrect.move(0, 200)
```

I want to move it to 50, 50  here can some one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top left corner of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. The center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

```py
check = pygame.image.load("check.png")
checkrect = check.get_rect(topleft = (50, 50))
```

Alternatively, you can set the position of the rectangle after the rectangle has been created:

```py
check = pygame.image.load("check.png")
checkrect = check.get_rect()
checkrect.topleft = (50, 50)
```